# LINQ Query on Huge List()

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq

I have a table in a database that stores page hits for websites. There are over ten million rows in this table. I want to add the latitude and longitude of the hit based off the IP address.  I have a separate table with geolocation information for IP ranges.  What I am trying to do is pull in the records from the page hits, take the IP address, convert it to an int and then find the range it falls in on the geolocation table and record that latitude and longitude in the page hits table.

The problem I am having is the length of time it is taking to do a lookup.  Here is what the table looks like (I am unsure how to represent this here, so hopefully this will suffice):

```
IPGeocodeLookup Table
------------------------------
IPAddressStart  varchar(50) 
IPAddressEnd    varchar(50) 
IPStartInt      numeric(20, 0)  
IPEndInt        numeric(20, 0)  
Country         varchar(256)    
StateProvince   varchar(256)    
District        varchar(256)    
City            varchar(256)    
Zipcode         varchar(50) 
Latitude        varchar(50) 
Longitude       varchar(50) 
GeonameID       varchar(50) 
TimezoneOffset  varchar(50) 
TimezoneName    varchar(50)
```

Initially, I just started with a SQL query:

```
var ipLong = /*the converted ip address */;
var qry = @"SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM IPGeocodeLookup WHERE @IpAddress BETWEEN IPStartInt AND IPEndInt";

var ipInfo = conn.Query<IPInfo>(qry, new { IpAddress = ipLong }).FirstOrDefault();
```

For reference, the IpInfo class looks like this:

```
public class IPInfo
{
    public long IPStartInt { get; set; }
    public long IPEndInt { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

This resulted in a 1-2 second lookup time. When having to process the entire table, this would result in over 6 months of running constantly.  I also noticed that when doing it this way, for some reason, my CPU spiked way up.

Next, I tried indexing the table.  I am very new to indexing tables, so I may not have done this right. What I did was went into SQL Server Manager and created a non-clustered index on IPStartInt and IPEndInt and I included Latitude and Longitude.  This decreased the speed to about 0.9 seconds per lookup and also solved the cpu spiking issue, so obviously I did something, I am just not sure if I did everything I could have as far as indexing goes. Also, even at this rate, I am still looking at a few months of processing time to make this happen.

Then I had an experimental idea. At the very start of the program, I loaded the entire IPGeocodeLookup table into a giant List():

```
string qry = @"SELECT IPStartInt, IPEndInt,  Latitude, Longitude FROM IPGeocodeLookup";
var ipTable = conn.Query<IPInfo>(qry).ToList();
```

Honestly, I thought the whole thing would take a giant memory dump, but to my surprise it worked after about 45 seconds of loading. What I then tried doing was using LINQ to query the List():

```
var ipInfo = (from item in ipTable where ipInt >= item.IPStartInt && ipInt <= item.IPEndInt select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

This actually cut my lookup time to around 0.4 seconds per lookup. Obviously, this is tons better, but it still leaves me running the program for around a month to entirely process the table.

So now I turn to Stack Overflow in the hopes that someone can look at what I have going on and tell me how I could possibly optimize this to run even quicker and hopefully get the time needed down to no more than a week. Thank you in advance and if I omitted any necessary information, please let me know.

Comment: You should do this whole thing in t-sql and get the application out of the way. You are trying to update an entire table with 10 million rows. Doing this row by agonizing row is going to suck the life out of your server.

Comment: You need to use a dictionary or hash table to reduce the look up time.  The key for a dictionary automatically uses a hash.  A straight list take an average of N/2 searches to find an item.  So if you have 10M entries it will take an average of 5M searches.  A hash is binary so it takes Log2(N).  So for 1M it only takes 24 searches instead of 5Million.

Comment: What is the point of populating `ipInfo`? What is the end goal for the retrieved value? If you are doing nothing more than updating one table based on another for an initial dump then you should do this with a "throw away" update statement. After initial population you can keep the DB up to date with the query you are starting to developer above but do not use EF to update millions of records (unless you just do not care about time).

Comment: @jdweng How will that help find the `item` that contains the value as opposed to a direct match?

Comment: You are using the IP ADDRESS as the key for the dictionary which is going to speed up the search time.

Comment: @jdweng Read again. He doesn't have the IP address in the geocode lookup table, he has ranges of ip addresses (start and end) and is searching for the range that contains his target IP address.

Comment: @DavidWebb How large is the IP Geocode Lookup table? How many rows?

Comment: @NetMage The Geocode table is 10.2 million rows

Comment: Use T-SQL... add proper indexing.  Minutes, not months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't get the SQL Server to be more efficient.

Create an `IComparer` to search by `IPEndInt`:

```
public class CompareIPInfo_By_IPEndInt : IComparer<IPInfo> {
    public int Compare(IPInfo x, IPInfo y) {
        return x.IPEndInt.CompareTo(y.IPEndInt);
    }
}
```

Use the `IComparer` to sort the `ipTable` (Geocode lookup table):

```
var endComparer = new CompareIPInfo_By_IPEndInt();
var index = ipTable.ToList();
index.Sort(endComparer);
```

Now you can use a function to binary search for matches:

```
IPInfo FindGeoInfo(int IPInt) {
    var findInfo = new IPInfo();
    findInfo.IPEndInt = IPInt;
    var idx = index.BinarySearch(findInfo);
    if (idx < 0) { // found inside range or didn't find
        var bidx = ~idx;
        if (bidx == ipTable.Count)
            return null;
        else
            return ipTable[bidx];
    }
    else // matched end of range
        return ipTable[idx];
}
```

Note: In .NET 4.5, you can create a `IComparer` from a lambda:

```
var endComparer = Comparer<IPInfo>.Create((a, b) => a.IPEndInt.CompareTo(b.IPEndInt));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  My lookups are now taking only a few milliseconds.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Someday I will finish writing my `Index` class for adding indexing to `List`s of objects without additional key/value storage, but now I see it should have a binary search / nearest neighbor version as well as hashed direct lookup, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the index on IPStartInt  and then  create a clustered index on IPStartInt. This will accelerate your search speed considerably.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should aim to do set operations in order to optimize the processing of the query. You could try an `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN`. Assuming the name of the page with the records is `pageHits`:

```
UPDATE h 
SET Latitude = l.Latitude, Longitude = l.Longitude 
FROM pageHits h
INNER JOIN IPGeocodeLookup l
ON h.IpAddress BETWEEN l.IPStartInt AND l.IPEndInt
```

I think this should perform better. Add indices for `h.Ipaddress` and `l.IPStartInt AND l.IPEndInt`.

You can test the performance by adding a `WHERE` statement to limit the number of rows you work on. For instance:

```
WHERE h.IpAddress < 10
```